# How to use Server 2008 as a media server (including XBox clients)

Tags: windows-server-2008, media-center, xbox360

Is there any way to use Windows Server 2008 R2 as a media server for XBox?  I want to be able to play (legally) ripped DVDs, stored on my server, without needing to install another computer or OS.

From what I understand, this is readily available as part of Home Server; but apparently Microsoft decided that no one running the (business) server software would have a reason to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using "tversity" http://tversity.com/ , its easy to setup, the Free addition can stream everything (except youtube etc) to your xbox with ease . 
The most important feature is that tversity , if setup correctly can auto transcode your vids/music so they work flawlessly on your xbox.